# App / curl still getting certificate expired error due to expired Let's Encrypt certificate

Tags: security, keychain, certificate

An open source app running on my macOS 10.13.6 and 10.14.6 system is failing to access a website via https that uses a Let's Encrypt certificate. If I use `curl` to access the same site, it also gets an error about the certificate being expired.

Here's the output of `curl -vv` with the hostname and IP address redacted:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://hostname/
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hostname (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default...
(rest of text not relevant and removed)
```

I've confirmed that the ISRG Root X1 certificate is installed in Keychain Access and is trusted.

Further, I can access the site using Safari or any other web browser. However, the app in question still fails, as does `curl`.

What do I need to do to fix this? I can't just use insecure mode on `curl` as the issue I'm trying to fix is the app that can't access the site. I'm not sure what library the app is using for https -- it may be libcurl, but I suspect it's failing for the same reason `curl` is.

Small addendum: the open source app is using OpenSSL 1.1.1j.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenSSL on macOS does not use the system keychain (which makes sense as it's a cross platform library) but rather has its own .pem file containing its root certificates. Even though my systems have a newer version of OpenSSL installed using homebrew and/or MacPorts, the system-wide OpenSSL pem file located at /etc/ssl/cert.pem was out of date and did not include the ISRG Root X1 certificate.

The solution:

1. Rename `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` to something else. (I suggest /etc/ssl/cert.pem.org)
2. Download the latest `cacert.pem` from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
3. Rename it to `cert.pem`
4. Copy it to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`

Now `curl` and any other app using OpenSSL can access websites signed using current Let's Encrypt certificates.

Alternatively, the MacPorts package `curl-ca-bundle` installs a pem file containing ISRG Root X1 to `/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` which can be used as well.

Other possible solutions:

- Manually add the ISRG Root X1 certificate to /etc/ssl/cert.pem
- Configure OpenSSL to use a different .pem file for its root certificates, such as `/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`

Comment: Nice. But there's a potential chicken-and-egg problem because curl.se is using a cert derived from the new ISRG Root X1, which you apparently don't trust yet. If you have a browser that *does* trust it, you can use that; otherwise you can get around the problem by downloading the new root collection with: `curl --insecure https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem -o cert.pem`

Comment: Fortunately that wasn't a problem for me since I'm not stuck using only curl. I just downloaded the new certificates using a browser. But if someone were in a position where they had to fix curl with curl then that's a good tip.

Comment: Thank you. This helped after trying 5 different solutions.

Comment: Excellent.  I called my old one .expired instead of .org